# Contentful Richtext Editor not showing on Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, contentful, richtext

I'm currently creating a blog with Next.js and Contentful. All was going fine until I came across issues with the Richtext editor.

The content is showing, however, there's no spacing between the lines?

Not sure how I can get it to look like what I've created on Contentful.

```
const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.NEXT_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "joshBlog",
  });

  return {
    paths: res.items.map((item) => ({
      params: { slug: item.fields.slug },
    })),
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "joshBlog",
    "fields.slug": params.slug,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      joshBlog: res.items[0],
    },
    revalidate: 30,
  };
}

export default function Article({ joshBlog }) {
    return (
        <div>
          <Head>
            <title>{joshBlog.fields.title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={joshBlog.fields.description} />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          </Head>
          <main className="mx-8 max-h-full md:px-40 px-4 pt-16 md:mx-24">
            <h1 className="text-2xl font-black pb-2 leading-9 mb-2 md:leading-relaxed md:text-4xl md:mb-4">
              {joshBlog.fields.title}
            </h1>
            <p className="mb-4 text-xs text-gray-600 font-light md:mb-10">
              {" "}
              Published: {joshBlog.fields.date}
            </p>
    
            <p className="font-light leading-6 text-xs mt-8 pb-2 text-justify text-gray-800 mb-2 md:font-normal md:text-base md:leading-loose">
              {joshBlog.fields.description}
            </p>
            <hr className="mt-4"></hr>
    
            <div className="">
              {documentToReactComponents(joshBlog.fields.content)}
            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[Rich text rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt7nm.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason why this was happening was due to Tailwind overriding the styles from Contentful.

In order to solve this issue:

Install: Tailwind Typography

Here is a link to the solution from [tailwind](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography)

Answer (score 2):

Because Richtext has to stay platform agnostic, Richtext includes line breaks as `\n`. These don't render as line breaks in React.

What you can do is to define a `renderOptions` object, tweak the `renderText` method and pass the options to `documentToReactComponents`.

```
const renderOptions = {
  renderText: text => {
    // break the string apart and inject <br> elements
    return text.split('\n').reduce((children, textSegment, index) => {
      return [...children, index > 0 && <br key={index} />, textSegment];
    }, []);
  },
};

// pass in render options and split text nodes on line breaks with a `<br>`.
documentToReactComponents(joshBlog.fields.content, renderOptions)
```

[You can find more Richtext tips in this article](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2021/05/27/rich-text-field-tips-and-tricks/).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment and help!  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work? I'm still getting the same result. 

I've shared more code on the post. 

Not sure if it has something to do with the way Im using Next js or Tailwind?

Comment: Also HTML tags dont seem to work -> e.g H3 tags aren't coming up when I console log

Comment: Have you had a look at the custom renderer? The snippets still don't include it. :) What are you logging? The surrounding code shouldn't matter. It's really about `documentToReactComponents`.

Comment: So I've managed to solve the issue. It was due to Tailwind overriding the styles! Thanks for persisting with my issue!